# Difference in API Calls in Production and Development?

Tags: django, rest, express, heroku, vercel

***Background:*** I have a backend server of a personal project, which makes call to a Third Party API. I have made this call in my own server instead of the React Front-End to avoid the CORS Error.

***Problem:*** When the backend is in Development, and the API call is done, it returns Correct Data. But once hosted, the API returns Incorrect Data.
By Incorrect, I mean response is of same format, but main content required (which is a URL) is incorrect.
I wanted to know more about what difference is between the two API calls my server does, one in localhost and the other in Production.

Here's how the Correct Response is which I get in Developement

```
{
  status: 200,
  message: "success",
  meta: "https://SOME_URL.com"
}
```

Here's what the incorrect response looks like which I get in Development

```
{
  status: 200,
  message: "success",
  meta: "https://SOM_OTHER_URL.com"
}
```

Note that the SOME_OTHER_URL actually Doesn't exist and gives 404, whereas, SOME_URL is a correct Domain.

***What I have figured out yet:***

1. I have used different hosting services, Heroku and Vercel, so, the Host is probably not the problem here.
2. I have created the backend in two Tech Stacks, Django and Node - Express, so that also checks out, as both return same incorrect Data in Production, whereas, both return Correct Data in Development.

Hence, I wanted to know about what data does API calls send over as request headers etc. and the difference between them when done in Development and Production.

Here's the Express Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        axios.post('THIRD_PARTY_API', {
            id: req.body.id
        })
        .then(resp => {
            console.timeLog
            res.status(200).json({
                'success': true,
                'body': JSON.stringify(resp.data)
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error("Error: ", err);
            return res.status(400).json("Server Error!");
        })
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json("Server Error!");
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

This provides correct Data when used in localhost, but not in Production.

Comment: Please include the code you use to do your API calls. As a first tip, look into [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/logging/) if you want to monitor what your application is doing under the hood.

Comment: Please have a look, have added the Express Code. And I have checked the Logs, they don't show anything that went wrong though.

Comment: It's still hard to know what's going on without knowing what kind of API your calling. Have a thorough look at if you can spot any differences between your local and the production environment. Do you use different API keys? Is there some kind of firewall/rate limiting on the API that blocks your production environment?

Comment: You can add logging to axios by using [interceptors](https://sabljakovich.medium.com/axios-interceptors-log-request-and-response-72b01333a760).

Comment: Will try logging in axios, and let you know.

Comment: Logging gave no extra results.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think I can help you further without knowing what the API address is, and what headers are sent.